SwiftUI StoreKit StoreFront Subscribe Button not working for all Subscription Options
In my straight forward Apple AppStore StoreKit SubscriptionView the Subscribe-button presented by the SubscriptionView is only working for one of two presented subscriptions. For the not working one, the UI animation "button pushed" is reacting, but nothing els happens. The working button works normally with proceeding to ApplePay sheet.
All functionality is coming from the StoreKit SubscriptionView storefront. My code has no influence on the behavior.
Both subscriptions are shown as approved in App Store Connect. GroupID is correct and crosschecked. If it would not be correct the working subscription could not work anyhow.
The button was working before, but had shown the non working behavior before as well. What I touched recently was enabling the Family Sharing option for both subscriptions a week ago. Can't say if there is a timely correlation here.
What might be the reason?
This is my code:
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct InAppPurchase: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SubscriptionStoreView(groupID: "21387xxx") {
                SubscriptionAdvertiser()
            }
            .storeButton(.visible, for: .redeemCode)

        }
    }
}


Crosschecked App Store Connect subscription settings
Crosschecked implementation
Consulted Apple Developer Support

Still no idea what might cause that behavior.
This is how the storefront looks like

I am late to this discussion, but might be running into the same issue. I find that if I have purchased a subscription already in a testing environment, I receive a success message without getting the purchase sheet first. If you're still encountering it, I believe this was being executed with the previous transaction:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/oninapppurchasecompletion(perform:)
I need to keep digging into it to learn more, and will post an update here if I discover the cause. Note that I have found the transaction manager helpful for testing scenarios:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/testing-in-app-purchases-with-storekit-transaction-manager-in-code#Inspect-transactions-with-the-transaction-manager
